# Character controller unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found a tutorial in youtube which is third person controller. The problem is, why does the character controller of my character is on the bottom?  The green one (I don't know what is it), it should cover the player's body right? Most of the tutorials that I watched, the character controller covers the player body. How can I fix that? Help me guys.  Thanks in advance.

**This what I'm talking about:**

[image]

**My Character:**
[image]

**Character Body:**
[image]

**Inspector**

[image]

Comment: You have to specify the dimensions of the controller via the inspector using the `Center`, `Radius`, and `Height` properties. You need to play with those properties to find what works best for your particular character. Just by looking at the screenshot you posted of the inspector I believe it will produce the small boundaries shown in the image above. Try setting radius to 5 and height to 15 and see what happens. Of course you'll need to move the center's `Y` property up some too.

Answer (score 1):

click the game object(player) in the inspector on the right find the capsule collider, and click edit collider. this will cause little blocks to appear on the collider in scene. if your having a hard time seeing the collider just double click the player object. once your in the edit collider mode you can grab the little squares on the collider and resize it with the mouse.